# Domain name validation of email using ngpattern

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to validate email in angularjs using ngpattern. I am new to angular, I searched the web, I got examples but I am confused about syntax to set ngpattern.

Example code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="controllerName">
        <ng-form name="mailForm">
            Email: <input type="text" ng-model="mail" name="mail" ng-pattern="re" /><br />
            <span ng-show="mailForm.mail.$error.pattern" style="color:red">Please enter correct email address.</span>
        </ng-form>
    </div>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module("app", []);
    app.controller('controllerName', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.mail = "visrosoftware@gmail.com";
        $scope.re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here in the code I don't know what ngpattern value means.
I am trying to validate the domain name for email address, 
Please help.

Comment: ng-pattern is somewhat which you expect from user to enter, and if he enters wrong then your error message should be shown

Comment: That string of characters is called a Regular Expression, in this case it tests if the string input matches valid email format. You should search and read more about its syntax.

Comment: If the goal is to enter an email address, what you want is not a domain name validation, but an email address validation. And you can have that just with `<input type="email" />`. ng-pattern is documented here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern. What don't you understand?

Comment: I didnt know about regular expressions.Now its ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are giving wrong pattern.
Try following :

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="formCtrl">
   <ng-form name="mailForm">
      Email: <input type="text" ng-model="mail" name="mail" ng-pattern="re" /><br />
     <span ng-show="mailForm.mail.$error.pattern" style="color:red">Please enter correct email address.</span>
  </ng-form>
</div>

function formCtrl($scope){
    $scope.re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
}
```

Also check Fiddle Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KGd8K/2613/)

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: Thank u for the answer

Comment: You can make it right answer if it worked for you, so that it can help others on stackoverflow